# What does `@@` mean as in src="@@ember" in a script tag (generated by `yo ember`)?

Tags: ember.js, yeoman

I tried out yeoman ember generator. In the generated `index.html`, I found these lines:

```
    <!-- build:js(app) scripts/components.js -->
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/handlebars/handlebars.runtime.js"></script>
    <script src="@@ember"></script>
    <script src="@@ember_data"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->
```

The `@@` symbol above is really disturbing to me. So, what do they mean? What program does this syntax belong to, i.e., what program understands this?

Comment: It's just for the build-tool to replace with the correct paths to ember.js. The comments around the block are for the usemin and usemin-prepare tasks but I'm pretty sure that these will be replaced before that (could be something as easy as a regular string replace in a custom task). As a sidenote, have you tried http://www.ember-cli.com? It's the recommended way to build ember apps and is maintained by Stefan Penner from the Ember core team.

Comment: So, you mean @@ember will become something like bower_components/ember/ember.js? BTW, thanks for mentioning ember-cli.

Comment: ember-cli is definitely correct answer

Comment: Exactly, that way it can link to the debug version while developing and the production version when building the published version.